# How to throttle requests to a cold flowable upstream

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a cold Flowable made with the generate method. I want to keep it cold but also want to "throttle" requests for additional items from it by the consumer. For example, if the consumer (subscriber?) takes 400ms to process the item, and throttling is set to 1 second I would expect to see a time line something like this:

```
0 - generate callback called to generate next value
1 - consumer starts processing generated value
401 - consumer finished processing value
401 - consumer requests next item
1000 - generate callback called to generate next value
```

This is the sample code I'm playing with to figure it out:

```kotlin
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    fun log(msg: String) {
        println(String.format("%s - %4d - %s", Thread.currentThread().name, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime, msg))
    }

    val generator = Flowable.generate<Int, Int>(
        Callable { 0 },
        BiFunction { state, emitter ->
            val value = state + 1
            log("generating $value")
            emitter.onNext(value)
            return@BiFunction value
        })

    val subscription = generator
        .concatMap { Flowable.concat(Flowable.just(it), Flowable.empty<Int>().delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), true, 1)
        .subscribe {
            log("processing $it")
            if (it % 5 == 0) {
                log("starting sleep")
                try { Thread.sleep(2200) } catch (e: InterruptedException) { log("interrupted") }
                log("done sleeping")
            }
        }

    Thread.sleep(8_000)
    subscription.dispose()
    log("done")
```

The output I get currently is this:

```
RxComputationThreadPool-1 -  278 - generating 1
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 -  283 - processing 1
RxComputationThreadPool-1 -  285 - generating 2
RxComputationThreadPool-2 - 1287 - generating 3
RxComputationThreadPool-2 - 1288 - generating 4
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 1288 - processing 2
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 2288 - processing 3
RxComputationThreadPool-4 - 3288 - generating 5
RxComputationThreadPool-4 - 3288 - generating 6
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 3288 - processing 4
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4289 - processing 5
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4289 - starting sleep
RxComputationThreadPool-6 - 5290 - generating 7
RxComputationThreadPool-6 - 5290 - generating 8
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 6489 - done sleeping
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 6489 - processing 6
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 7490 - processing 7
main - 8265 - done
```

The output I *want* to get is something this:

```
RxComputationThreadPool-1 -  278 - generating 1
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 -  283 - processing 1
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 1285 - generating 2 // 2 generated one second after 1
RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 - 1287 - processing 2 // but once generated, processed immediately
RxComputationThreadPool-2 - 2288 - generating 3 // 3 generated one second after 2
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 2288 - processing 3 
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 3289 - generating 4 // 4 generated one second after 3
RxCachedThreadScheduler-4 - 3289 - processing 4
RxComputationThreadPool-4 - 4290 - generating 5 // 5 generated one second after 4
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4290 - processing 5
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4290 - starting sleep // item 5 takes longer to process
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 6491 - done sleeping  // 2200ms later its done
RxComputationThreadPool-6 - 6492 - generating 6 // now that consumer is done, it requests next item and gets generated immediately since it has been 1 second since last request
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 6492 - processing 6
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 7492 - generating 7 // 7 generated one second after 6
RxCachedThreadScheduler-4 - 7493 - processing 7
main - 8265 - done
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to generate a new value exactly 1 sec after processing previous value no matter how long processing took?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to want to make sure that there is at least 1 second between each generate call. If the processing takes 5sec, then new value should be generated immediately once the processing finished (since it has been > 1sec since last generate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [RxJavaExtensions (RxJava2 version)](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions/tree/v0.20.10) transformers should be a solution to your problem – [`spanout()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions/tree/v0.20.10#flowabletransformersspanout). It inserts delay between emissions from upstream. I have changed just one line in your code (replaced `concatMap()` by `spanout()`):

```java
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
fun log(msg: String) {
    println(String.format("%s - %4d - %s", Thread.currentThread().name, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime, msg))
}

val generator = Flowable.generate<Int, Int>(
    Callable { 0 },
    BiFunction { state, emitter ->
        val value = state + 1
        log("generating $value")
        emitter.onNext(value)
        return@BiFunction value
    })

val subscription = generator
    .compose(FlowableTransformers.spanout(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) // <– changed line
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), true, 1)
    .subscribe {
        log("processing $it")
        if (it % 5 == 0) {
            log("starting sleep")
            try { Thread.sleep(2200) } catch (e: InterruptedException) { log("interrupted") }
            log("done sleeping")
        }
    }

Thread.sleep(8_000)
subscription.dispose()
log("done")
```

Produced output:

```
RxComputationThreadPool-1 -  153 - generating 1
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 1178 - processing 1
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 1179 - generating 2
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 2176 - processing 2
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 2177 - generating 3
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 3177 - processing 3
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 3178 - generating 4
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4175 - processing 4
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 4175 - generating 5
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 5177 - processing 5
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 5178 - starting sleep
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 7383 - done sleeping
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 7384 - generating 6
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 7384 - processing 6
RxComputationThreadPool-1 - 7385 - generating 7
main - 8151 - done
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you! And thankfully I was already using the library for some other transformers.